# webrtc - GetStats() call OnStatsDelivered with an empty RTCStatsReport

Tags: c++, webrtc

I'm using new **WebRTC stats API** with **RTCStatsCollectorCallback** object that is called when stats report is generated. I'm invoke GetStats() and then I can see that **OnStatsDelivered** is called with a RTCStatsReport that contains just one (empty) item in stats_ member. In **GetStats()** call I pass my own implementation of RTCStatsCollectorCallback that implements webrtc::RTCStatsCollectorCallback interface. My question is, is neccessary some setup or constraints in PeerConnection in order to get RTCStatsReport with the metrics? I mean, to get, for example kStatsValueNameRtt stat, I need to set something in PeerConnection. Note that I'm using **C++ native API** in branch **55**. Is this new stats API full implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the older `GetStats` method with success:

```
bool GetStats(StatsObserver* observer,
            webrtc::MediaStreamTrackInterface* track,
            StatsOutputLevel level) override;
```

It could be your problem was due to trying to use an in-progress API (webrtc framework is a bit wild west). Currently, peerconnectiointernface.h says the following:

```
// Gets stats using the new stats collection API, see webrtc/api/stats/. These
// will replace old stats collection API when the new API has matured enough.
// TODO(hbos): Default implementation that does nothing only exists as to not
// break third party projects. As soon as they have been updated this should
// be changed to "= 0;".
virtual void GetStats(RTCStatsCollectorCallback* callback) {}
```

As I'm writing this response, your question is 6 months old, so it's possible the this new API is now working (though the comment above suggests otherwise).